# Godot Exporting for Universal Windows Platform is not clear (GDscript)

Tags: export, win-universal-app, godot, gdscript

The description on the main site is not complete and clear! Please show me how to make a program for the Universal Windows Platform(UWP) with a clear and complete description step by step.

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_uwp.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Godot 3.2.2, exporting for UWP is currently broken; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/30558).

We should probably unexpose it from the Export dialog until it's fixed.